# How can I get Json data with Python?

Tags: python, json, rest

What I want to do is to get Json data out as a list (or array) with Python, I tried several times but didn't work. My json data is like this:

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "List":{
        "stuff":[{
            "id":"326",
            "name":"a",
            "url":"autob-fulla.tgz",
        },{
            "id":"327",
            "name":"b",
            "url":"auto-fullb.tgz",
        },{
            "id":"328",
            "name":"c",
            "url":"auto-fullc.tgz",
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to return all the value of "id". Now my code is like this:

```
import json
def retrieve():
    print('retrieving results...')
    testQueueID = '1';
    base_url1 = 'http://localhost:8080/stuff'
    conn = Connection(base_url1, username='admin', password='admin')
    resp = conn.request_get("", args={}, headers={'content-type':'application/xml', 'accept':'application/xml'})
    decoded_json = json.loads(json.dumps(resp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, skipkeys=True))
    return decoded_json
```

Comment: Your code appears to be requesting XML, yet you're talking about decoding JSON. What's going on here?

Comment: my bad, header should be: headers = {'content-type':'application/xml', 'accept':'application/json'}

Comment: In that case, you probably shouldn't be using `json.dumps` here - `json.loads()` should be all you need.

Comment: yeah, Yahoo! it works... Thank you, my friend. You are actually GOOD. Thank you, Amber. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave out the `json.dumps` call. You already have a string with JSON in it, so all you need is `json.loads()`.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should click the green checkmark to the left of it to mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

1.) xml != Json

2.) Try this http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/json/ first. It ll teach you.

3.) Simple code to get you started . See what data prints.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('json_datafile')

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
json_data.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, Vrashabh. Lemme try this one.

Comment: I tried:json_data=open('parameter.json')
    data = json.load(json_data)----the last line gets error

Comment: ret = conn.request_post("/bynewbuild/", body=content, headers=headers)
abc = ret[u'body']
json_data=open(abc)
in this case, the error is: "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'{"......."

Comment: Then I did this:    
json_data=open('parameter.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

File "D:\workspaces\TestPythonProject\src\MyTest.py", line 50, in callRESTschedulerAPI
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end =

Comment: Sorry, Lafada. I guess I'm giving you a headache. I still couldn't figure out how to post code in comments. Hope you would understand what I posted in here. Still, I want more solution on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you've marked an answer right, so I am assuming you dont need more help here?

Comment: Thank you for asking, Vrashabh. For now, it's okay for me with all these answers. They really are helped. Have a nice day. :-)

Comment: even I got error. Even after I added pprint to python scripts folder